R qgraph group plot with uneven node number
I am creating a network plot with groups of different node numbers. I want to adjust the size of the circles according to the number of nodes, so the groups with more nodes will look bigger and there will be little to no overlap between the nodes. Here is a reproducible example:
library(qgraph)
data(big5)
data(big5groups)
# Compute correlation matrix:
big5_cors <- cor_auto(big5, detectOrdinal = FALSE)
UnevenGroups <- list(
  Group1 = c(1:100),
  Group2 = c(101:180),
  Group3 = c(181:200),
  Group4 = c(201:240)
)
# Correlations:
big5Graph <- qgraph(cor(big5),minimum=0.25,groups=UnevenGroups,
                    legend=TRUE,borders=FALSE, title = "Big 5 correlations")

I hope someone can help me in customizing the size of the circles from qgraph group plot
